# Name under black package in package-lock.json keeps removing and adding automatically

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, package-lock.json

On `npm install`, I see that in `package-lock.json` property `packages[""].name` is sometimes removed and sometimes added. How to prevent this change, since it appears in git changes?

[image: package-lock.json]

Comment: did you try to remove the node_modules file and this package.lock.json file? Please do that and then again install "Npm install", that'd be solved.

Comment: Yeah. I'm wondering if someone knows the reason.

Comment: None of the answers are satisfactory yet. At work we've some shared packages, and after some clean install the package-lock.json files have been updated with this `name` despite the fact those shared packages have had the `name` property since the beginning. It's kind of odd.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this behaviour that name is added when package.json has a name that is different from project root directory name.

`projectdir/package.json` with name="projectdir" => no name in `package-lock.json`

`projectdir/package.json` with name="anothername" => name="anothername" in `package-lock.json`

Comment: I have the same issue, but my project folder name and the name in the package.json are the same

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem an found the solution to remove the package name in package.json file.
So I remove this line:

```
"name": "My package name",
```